# Android - center text in OpenSansBTextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm designing my constraint layout using XML.

I have an `OpenSansBTextView` and I need my text to be centered in it. It's centered **horizontally**, and *not* centered vertically. I don't know why. Here is my xml file. Can you see my mistake?

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:id="@+id/dashboard">

    <com.doyousonder.android.utils.RochesterTextView
        android:id="@+id/YourActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.34"
        android:text="@string/YourActivity"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryMoreDark"
        android:textSize="23sp" />

    <com.doyousonder.android.utils.OpenSansRTextView
        android:id="@+id/YouVoted"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/YourActivity"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:text="@string/YouVoted"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryMoreDark"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <com.doyousonder.android.utils.OpenSansSBTextView
        android:id="@+id/VoteCount"
        android:layout_width="29dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/YouVoted"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/YouVoted"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/YouVoted"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/more_curved_edge_button_button_primarycolor_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
```

Comment: what is opensansbtextview?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed a normal textview redesigned with some added features only

Comment: post the code for custom text view you are using

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided much code to work with, i.e what is the `youVoted` variable. I'm assuming `youvoted` is your parent layout

I think you're issue comes with how you set up your constraints. Try these instead

```
...other layout info
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/YouVoted"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/YouVoted"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/YouVoted"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/YouVoted"/>
```

**Explanation**
I believe the mistake is you made is stating your textview should start at the end of your `youvoted` layout instead of saying it should ***start at the start*** of the `youvoted` layout.

**change** `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/YouVoted"` to `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/YouVoted"`

also add an end constraint.

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/YouVoted"
```